# How to get default CIDR block for my EC2 instances with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'd like to create security group which allow me to communicate between instances within subnet and don't expose some ports outside.
Of course I can explicite specify my CIDR, but how create data source which give me CIDR block for my subnet in default VPC?

Comment: Can you share your Terraform code to show what you've tried so far and explain how that's not working for you? If you get an error could you also include the full error in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with terraform data source [aws_vpc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/vpc.html), you can get what you need.

The example shows what you need.

```
variable "vpc_id" {}

data "aws_vpc" "selected" {
  id = "${var.vpc_id}"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "example" {
  vpc_id            = "${data.aws_vpc.selected.id}"
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  cidr_block        = "${cidrsubnet(data.aws_vpc.selected.cidr_block, 4, 1)}"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question about providing a security group for a CIDR range containing EC2 instances. It would be improved if you could provide a better example but I suspect the OP's question is better answered by instead directing them to allow inbound traffic from other security groups.

Comment: Enough directly for me.Thanks. :)